# Why does deleting an allocated array cause a memory error?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, allocation

I implemented an ArrayList class for education purposes but I am running into a memory error when deleting the array in my expand() method.

Here is my class and all important methods:

```
//create array with default size 2
template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(){
    realSize = 2;
    count = 0;
    data = new T[realSize];
}

//destructor
template<class T>
ArrayList<T>::~ArrayList() {
    delete []data;
}

//adds value to end of list
template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::add(T val) {
    //if reached end of array, expand array
    if (count >= realSize)
        expand();
    data[count] = val;
    count++;
}

//inserts value at index
template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::insert(T val, int index) {
    if (!isValid(index)) return;
    //if index is greater than current size, expand
    while (index >= realSize || count >= realSize) {
        expand();
    }
    //shift values before index
    for (int i = count; i >= index; i--) {
        T val = data[i];
        data[i + 1] = data[i];
    }
    data[index] = val;
    count++;
}

//return value at index
template<class T>
T ArrayList<T>::get(int index) {
    if (!isValid(index)) return 0;
    return data[index];
}

template<class T>
int ArrayList<T>::size() {
    return count;
}

template<class T>
void ArrayList<T>::expand() {
    //double array size
    realSize = realSize * 2;
    T* newData = new T[realSize];
    //replace data
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        newData[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[]data; //<--ERROR OCCURS HERE
    data = newData;
}
```

Here is some code that will cause the bug

```
    ArrayList<int>* list = new ArrayList<int>();

    list->add(1);
    list->add(5);
    list->insert(2, 1);
    list->insert(3, 2);
    list->insert(4, 3); //<---ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

The error is a message box that reads

> Debug Error!
>
> Program:
>   ...ommunity\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatorm\testhost.x86.exe
>
> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#296) at 0x05D69BC0
>
> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Why would this cause an error occasionally when calling the expand method? As far as I can tell, the array is in expected order when expand() is called (in my example, it is `{1, 2, 3, 5}`).

Comment: There are unrelated, but further issues with your `expand` function, such as adjusting member variables before calling `new[]`.  If `new[]` throws an exception, you now have an object that has wrong values.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will flip the adjustment and the memory allocation to account for failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `insert` method.  When you are copying the existing elements up to make space for the new element, you start at element `count`, and copy `data[count]` up one slot to `data[count + 1]`.  However, no element has been stored at `data[count]` and under the correct circumstances the access to `data[count + 1]` will access past the space allocated for `data`.

Those circumstances happen with the second `insert` call.  `count` is 3, `realsize` is 4, and `index` is 2, so no expansion happens.  Your for loop will then assign `data[count + 1] = data[count]`, which is `data[4] = data[3]`.  Since data only has space for 4 elements, writing to `data[4]` clobbers data past the end of the allocated space, which is detected on a later memory operation (in this case, when the allocated space is freed via a call to `delete`).

The solution is to start your loop at `int i = count - 1`, or decrement it in the condition:

```
for (int i = count; --i >= index; )
```

Unrelated, the `T val = data[i];` declaration does nothing useful and can be removed.

Comment: Oh I see. So it was a fencepost error, correct? I didn't realize setting the data beyond the size of the error could result in errors when deleting! And I didn't realize I was setting data outside the range at all, either.

The line you mentioned at the end was my attempt at debugging, as I assumed there was may be an issue with the insert() method because the errors did not appear until I started using it.

Thank you for your help.